# How can I group the a list into tuple grouped items in Scala?

Tags: scala

for example how can I convert

```
val list=(1 to 10).toList
```

into

```
List((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `grouped` method for the List class: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

```
list.grouped(2).toList.collect { case a :: b :: Nil => (a,b) }
res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (9,10))
```

`collect` is used to convert list of lists to list of tuples.